# How to set resolution to 1334x750 for my iPhone app?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, opengl-es

I have an application which I am coding and when  I launch it the display resolution is  960x480 and my iPhone 6 has a screen of 1334x750.

It is an OpenGL es app and in a class viewController which inherits from GLKViewController, I am using a variable of type GLKView to init display in the viewDidLoad method from the ViewController class.

In which method  in the program do I have to init the resolution and what can I do to set the correct one (1334x750)?

Comment: describing what the code does, doesnt solve anything. try posting some code

Answer (score 0):

You can use below methods to get screen's width and height dynamically, this works on all devices (iPhone 5, 6, 6+, iPad, etc). Current values are for landscape mode, you can swap them for Portrait mode if required..

```
+(int)screenWidth
{

    return MAX([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height);
}

+(int)screenHeight
{

    return MIN([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height);
}
```

You must be initializing GLKView, so just set the [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds] to its frame.

Comment: It gave me 480 x 320, are sure it is this ?

Comment: are you using any 3rd party library?, may be try searching in your project if it is hardcoded somewhere, because dynamically these two methods return current device's width and height.